# Magento - Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted change the php memory limit also

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1450 bytes) Also changed the php_memory_limit till 1024M then also same error is raised. The error i got while importing product csv from frontend in magento.

Comment: Did you change the php_memory_limit in php.ini file directly?

Comment: Yes changed it in cpanel also tried giving it in code.